# How to check "stripsize" of a stripped logical volume?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, storage, lvm

I have created a `stripped logical volume` using below command:

```
lvcreate -L 1G -n lv1 -i 2 -I 128 myvg1 /dev/nvme0n1p5 /dev/nvme0n2p6
```

Now, how can I check the `stripsize` again?

I have tried using commands `lvs`, `lvscan` and `lvdisplay ---v /dev/myvg1/lv1`.

None of them is giving information about the strip size.

Comment: It’s “striped”, by the way, as in tiger stripes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that command, it should show you the stripe size of each LV (-a) in the last column of output (stated with + are additional columns to be listed besides the standard ones)

```
lvs -ao +lv_full_name,devices,stripe_size
```

Example output, though no striping configured:

```
root@puppet [130] ~ > lvs -ao +lv_full_name,devices,stripe_size
  LV      VG         Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert LV                 Devices         Stripe
  lv_root VolGroup00 -wi-ao---- 47.49g                                                     VolGroup00/lv_root /dev/sda2(0)        0
  lv_root VolGroup00 -wi-ao---- 47.49g                                                     VolGroup00/lv_root /dev/sdb(0)         0
  lv_swap VolGroup00 -wi-ao----  2.00g                                                     VolGroup00/lv_swap /dev/sda2(4479)     0
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please also provide some explanation of the command? Thanks again!

Comment: Done, edited the answer to some extent.

Comment: thanks. i have accepted the answer. Can you explain the meaning of `+lv_full_name,devices,stripe_size`?

Comment: that's now done as well